# Step size selection for gradient descent without access to function evaluations

Tags: convex-optimization

Is there a way to select step size to do gradient descent when you only have access to gradient evaluations, but not function evaluations?

I know the function to be optimized over is convex, and given a point x, I have access to f'(x), but not f(x). Can I do anything other than a fixed step size rule for gradient descent in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to [estimate the Lipschitz Constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709835) of the function in a local area.
Then you'll be able to estimate the bound on the step size.